# With what classes of functions the equality $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x) \, dx$ leads to paradoxes?

Tags: laplace-transform, divergent-integrals

The following operators keep the area under the convergent integrals unchanged:

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x) \, dx=\int_0^\infty\frac1x\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t[ f(t)](x)\,dx$$

But with divergent integrals applying the transform $\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x)$ (I would denote it $\mathcal{T}f(x)$) to a function more than once may lead to a strictly greater or smaller function, which I refer to as an unacceptable *paradox*.

One such example is the function $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$. Applying the transform $\mathcal{T}$ to it twice, one arrives at function $\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{x}}$, which is strictly greater than the original function, and the problematic step seems to be the first one. It seems, one class of the problematic functions is $f(x)=\frac1{x^p}$, where $0<p<1$.

So, I wonder, what is the whole description of the class of the functions that lead to such paradoxes. I outline the two paradoxes I am seeking to avoid:

1. Functions such that $f(x)>\mathcal{T^n}[f(x)]$ or $f(x)<\mathcal{T^n}[f(x)]$ for all $x>0$, that is the function becomes strictly smaller or greater after the transform.
2. Functions such that the integral $\int_0^\infty (f(x)-\mathcal{T^n}[f(x)])dx$ is finite but nonzero.

Is it possible to clearly describe the class of functions than lead to such *paradoxes* so to avoid them?

Or should the assumed equivalence be modified to add some other terms?

Comment: Can we calculate integrals in the same way using Mellin Transformations?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I don't know

Comment: I found: $$\int_0^{\infty } f(t) \, dt=\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{\mathcal{M}_t^{-1}[f(t)](x)}{x \ln (x)} \, dx$$ ,but I can't get with  **Mellin Transform**?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk nice formula with inverse Mellin transform! I will try with Mathematica.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I am not sure if your formula is correct, but inverse to $-\frac{\mathcal{M}_t^{-1}[f(t)](x)}{x \ln (x)}$ is $-\mathcal{M}_t[t\ln t f(t)](x)$

Comment: Thanks. Works fine :)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I have tested your formula on one example and it works. The transform $-\frac{\mathcal{M}_t^{-1}[f(t)](x)}{x \ln (x)}$ applied to the function $\frac1{x+1}$ gives $-\frac{\theta (1-x)}{\log (x)}$. We can write its integral as $\int_0^1 \frac{-1}{\log(x)}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{-1}{\log(1-x)}dx$ Now, lets compare it to $1/x$: $\int_0^1 \left(-\frac{1}{\log (1-x)}-\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx=-\gamma$, exacly as expected. This transform opens a big new class of equivalence relations in divergent integrals. Still, the original question remains.